# Is it possible to add comments to .tx files for textx? If so, how?

Tags: textx

Was working through the [hello-world](https://textx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/hello_world/#hello-world-example) example in the docs.

I then realized I wanted to add comments to help me learn the textX syntax better.

There's no indication that this is possible in the first place. Googling didn't help.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/igordejanovic/textX/blob/master/docs/grammar.md#grammar-comments):

> **Grammar comments**
>
> Syntax for comments inside a grammar is // for line comments and /* ... */ for block comments.